# how to use correctly semicolon when importing products in Magento with CSV

Tags: magento, ms-office

I'm trying to generate a CSV products file which i want to import into magento database. 
If i use semicolon for CSV and I have some product description which have semicolon inside, how to write CSV correctly to avoid conflicts of semicolon ?

I hope it is something easy like adding a backslash:  **\;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The semicolon inside description will not make any adverse effect.

Use open office calc to create the csv file.While saving the file as csv use UTF-8 format